# Running a docker login with python subprocess securely

Tags: python, docker, security

I want to run a docker login from python3 without asking for user input.
I have three global variables `REGISTRY_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD`.

I want to run:

```
os.system(f"echo '{PASSWORD}' | docker login {REGISTRY_URL} -u {USERNAME} --password-stdin")
```

The problem is that my three global variables are user controllable which can lead to Remote Code Execution.

How can I run this command securely with `subprocess.run` ?

(NB: I do not want to use `-p` option of docker because it is not secure as per docker recommandation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can supply the password using the `input` argument to subprocess.run:

```
import subprocess

def docker_login(registry_url, username, password):
    command = ["docker", "login", registry_url, "-u", username, "--password-stdin"]
    completed_process = subprocess.run(command, input=password.encode() + b'\n', capture_output=True)
    
    if completed_process.returncode == 0:
        print("Docker login successful!")
    else:
        print("Docker login failed. Error message:")
        print(completed_process.stderr.decode())

docker_login(REGISTRY_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```